# Processing return of async call in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Suppose there is a `async read(args)` method that returns some data. 
I use `redux-thunk` and `redux-promise` to dispatch async actions.
The method needs access to the redux store to be able to read certain parts of the state tree, and the extra arguments passed to `thunkMiddleware.withExtraArguments()`. The method is an abstraction and specific implementations of the method may need to access different parts of the state tree (for example, ID of the current session, name of the data source etc.).
The data returned from the method needs to be post-processed before it is passed to the component that does the rendering.

I am considering the following approaches to implement the above:

**Approach 1.** pass the `getState` function to the `async read()` method; implement action creator like this:

```
  const actionRead=()=>async (dispatch, getState, {rpc})=>{
   dispatch({type:ActionReadStarted, ...});
   let data=await read(rpc, getState);
   // post process the data as needed
   dispatch({type:ActionReadComplete, data});
  };
```

What I don't like here is the `getState` that is passed directly to the `read` method.

**Approach 2.** Make the `read()` method an action creator itself:

```
const actionRead=()=>async (dispatch, getState, {rpc})=>{
 dispatch({type:ActionReadStarted, ...});
 let data=await dispatch(read());
 // post process the data as needed
 dispatch({type:ActionReadComplete, data});
};

const read=()=>(dispatch, getState, {rpc})=>{
 const arguments=getState().some_arguments;
 return rpc.actual_read_returns_promise(arguments);
}
```

In both cases, reducer simply writes the data to the store. I can't put post-processing logic in the reducer, because it may cause side effects.

I personally favor the second approach, but this post advises that `dispatch` should not return any data: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/61

My questions to the gurus: which approach is more in line with the `react-redux` best practices? is there a better way to implement the above?

**EDIT:**
Right now I am going with the modified first approach:

```
const actionRead=(args)=>async (dispatch, getState, api)=>{
 dispatch({type:ActionReadStarted, ...});
 let data=await read(args)(dispatch, getState, api);
 // post process the data as needed
 dispatch({type:ActionReadComplete, data});
};

const read=(args)=>(dispatch, getState, {rpc})=>{
 const arguments=getState().some_arguments;
 return rpc.actual_read_returns_promise({...args, ...arguments});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each reducer has access to it's own slice of state so it should not need any data passed to it that exists already in it's own state.  When you have an action that needs to update multiple slices of state that are part of separate reducers, each reducer should listen to the action and modify its own state separately.  This decoupling of action and reducer is one of the things I feel that makes redux very powerful.

So, in my opinion the best way to do this is to dispatch an action such as "READ" with whatever comes back from the read function.  Then each reducer that contains state that must be modified due to that action would listen for the "READ" action and then modify it's own state.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response, and I agree that modifying the state in the reducer it is the most obvious thing to do. However, I mentioned in my question that "I can't put post-processing logic in the reducer, because it may cause side effects." That is based on the recommendation that reducers must be pure functions (see http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html for example). In my case, post-processing of the data is certainly not a pure function because it relies on the data from other multiple sources. So I have to look for a solution that does post-processing elsewhere